How to change accessorKey value based on row value
{
    accessorKey: "userId",
    header: ({ column }) => (
      <DataTableColumnHeader column={column} title="User Id" />
    ),
    cell: ({ row }) => (
      <label>{row?.original?.subRetailerId ?? row?.original?.retailerId}</label>
    ),
},

How to change accessorKey from userId to userId2 when retailerId exists
I am working on sorting it giving me accessorKey or id if exists so i want change accessorKey value from userId to userId2 when retailerId exists else it should be userId

You will need to handle this in your data. Assuming each Obj in the data array has a userId, userId2, and retailerId, where retailerId may have no value, you could do something like this: data.map(row =>({ ...row, userIdColumn: row.retailerId ? row.userId2 : row.userId}) and pass the mapped result into useReactTable as data. Then in columns, change accessorKey: "userId" to accessorKey: "userIdColumn"
